# method returning 0 on excel file but a real value on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm exporting a model to an excel file. One of my columns has the following:

```
k << kid.number_of_native_conversations rescue "0"
```

but I'm always getting "0"; if I run the following on my console (with the same kid object):

```
kid.number_of_native_conversations rescue "0"
```

I get "61" and this is the real value. Could anybody help me to understand why is this happening and how to solve this issues?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step: since there is a chance that the method 'natively' returns 0, I would change the `return "0"` to `return "error"` or similar to see if an error is raised or the counting failed in the method. From there I would maybe just remove the `rescue` to actually see what error was raised (that's one disadvantage of this kind of error handling, it easily hides the true cause of errors).

Comment: Good point. For example, if kid is nil or some other object that doesn't have a `number_of_native_conversations` method you'll get "0" returned.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but why the same kid object return something different on console???

Comment: Presumably some of the code that precedes the `number_of_native_conversations` call is different. Or even `k` is not accepting the `<<`.

Comment: umm ok ok, I got it, thanks so much!

Comment: Using rescue here will mask all errors, why not `(kid.try :number_of_native_conversions) || "0"`